# Pending Intent with Notifications in KitKat (4.4.4)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to get the Implicit Intent sent when the user taps on a notification. This is my code:

```
        // Intent used to share data
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        notificationIntent.setType("text/plain");
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Intent message to share
        String intentString = "I took " + stepsAlarm.getText() + " steps";
        notificationIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, intentString);

        // Create a pending intent that triggers only when the notification is selected
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //Resources res = context.getResources();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_not)
                //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setTicker("Stepmeter")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Stepmeter Alert")
                .setContentText("You took " + stepsAlarm.getText() + " steps");
        Notification n = builder.build();

        nm.notify(7, n);
```

The notification shows up just fine, but when I select it nothing happens. I also added the Intent-filter to the manifest like so:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PendingIntent.getActivity()` instead of `getService()`. Since, you want to start a new activity on clicking the notification.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` instead of `getService` since you are not starting a service.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to PendingIntent.getBroadcast same result.